# Py2app/Pygame error: Library not loaded

Tags: python, pygame, py2app

When I compile my pygame app with py2app, I get the following error. I assume it has something to do with the pygame mixer that I added in this new version. Does anyone know what this error is all about?

```
Library not loaded: @executable_path/../MacOS/../MacOS/../MacOS/../MacOS/../Frameworks/smpeg.framework/Versions/A/smpeg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing [smpeg library](http://www.lokigames.com/development/smpeg.php3) on your system.